# Nullable ForeignKey field Django

Tags: django-models

I am using django and sqlite to create a simple shop. I have a model with nullable foreign key. But when i want to add an item using admin it stops me in the foreign key field. Please help, because i don't understand why it doesn't work:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id_order = models.ForeignKey(Order, null = True, default = None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    type_item = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    other = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    color = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    cost = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    is_available_now = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    available_count = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = "images/")
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You miss `blank=True` in foreign key field. `null` is just to database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/

Comment: It works, thanks. It is really strange, because i try to do "blank=true" before. Thanks

Comment: You need both. Blank to be not mandatory, null to store null value.